# 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted in Rails Mailer using Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail, actionmailer

I am using Rails Mailer and Gmail to send emails. But I keep getting the `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted` error.

I checked out other questions regarding this problem but unfortunately, they didn't help.

I have a 2-step authentication enabled and I did create the App Password for my Rails app.

This is my configuration in `production.rb`:

```rb
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'myhost'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    domain: 'myhost',
    port: 587,
    user_name: 'myemail@domain.com',
    password: ENV['GMAIL_APP_PASSWORD'],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Now, it is worth noting that I am using a non-Gmail address but I am using GSuite which allows me to log in to Gmail with that address and use it pretty much as a Gmail address.

If it means anything, after trying to send an email with Rails I did receive an email about Blocked login alert. And to note again, I am using the App Password, not the general password for the account.

Seen some answers saying that I have to enable less secure apps option but I can't enable it while 2-step is active.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I've run into the same problem and can't figure out what to do -- wrote it up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77382027/why-cant-i-send-emails-from-rails-in-production-using-a-typical-actionmailer-co (resisted the urge to just copy and paste your question :)

Comment: See my answer to my own question if you're using `.rbenv-vars` files and still have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Less secure apps

Have you allowed for less secure apps?  Please do so, and see if that helps.  [Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

## Clear Captcha

[Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

## 2fa use an app password.

If using 2 Step Verification in Gmail, you may need an application  password. [Create & use App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

[image: Use "recent" mode if you are using POP3 on multiple devices. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en]

## Xoauth2

If it still doesnt work you may need to consider checking [xoauth2-protocol](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

The Less Secure Apps had already been removed by Google due to security updates as of May 2022. Doing the 2fa use an app password did it for me as of the time I've added this comment.