# Why can't I send emails from Rails in production using a typical ActionMailer config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

I had a look at [535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted in Rails Mailer using Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616524/535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted-in-rails-mailer-using-gmail) and their problem is similar to mine, and I'm not sure they got it resolved.

I set up 2fa with an app password on a gmail account.

I want to send account-activation and password-reset emails through that gmail account to our users.

Here's my configuration:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'appname.com',  # has not gone on line yet - does that matter?
    :user_name => ENV['GMAIL_APP_USER'],    # "appname123@gmail.com"
    :password =>  ENV['GMAIL_APP_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :openssl_verify_mode => 'none',
  }
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'appname.com' } 
# again, it's not on line yet, but it seems like I need something
# I haven't found what exactly this field is for
```

Whenever I hit the endpoint that would deliver an email, I get this in my logs:

```
I, INFO -- : Delivered mail 653ddda3b6a7f_864d349fc5244b@MYHOSTNAME.mail (287.1ms)
   [ ("MYHOSTNAME" is my actual hostname, but it's not mentioned in the above config) ]
I, INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 587ms (ActiveRecord: 16.5ms | Allocations: 18589)
F, FATAL -- :
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
):

app/models/user.rb:35:in `send_activation_email'
app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

From another post I could see that the "Learn more" error message is from gmail/google,
and basically that post told me to use an app password.

I *am* using an app password, and have enabled 2FA on that email account.

The app password as delivered consists of 4 sets of four-letter-sequences,
each followed by one space. Whether I leave the spaces in or not, I get the same
result.

Is there something I need to do to let gmail know this is an app password,
and I haven't leaked the actual account password?

I've read a couple of dozen posts on this subject, and all say the same thing.
Leading me to think I've failed to do something obvious.

The code's in github, but the credentials aren't. So if anyone's interested in
digging in that deep, please get in touch with me and I'll explain how I
feed the creds to the Rails app.

Comment: Some tips here - use `ENV.fetch('GMAIL_APP_USER')` instead of just the square brackets. This will raise an error instead of just letting you assign nil which will save a lot of debugging time. Also instead of ENV vars and `.rbenv-vars` consider using [Rails encrypted secrets instead](https://web-crunch.com/posts/the-complete-guide-to-ruby-on-rails-encrypted-credentials).

Comment: Right, but that still wouldn't have fixed the problem of the extraneous double quotes. I checked the github issues, and there was a response from Sam saying just don't quote the values. I don't know how the quotes stick, as it's a bash implementation, but not going to persue it...

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...

Do not use double-quotes around your secrets in your `.rbenv-vars` file,
or they'll become part of the actual string.

And you can pull the spaces out of the google app passwords. They separate them into four pieces so you can yell it across the room to your co-worker and not lose track of where you are.